# Existence of the derivative of the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{1-e^{\frac{1}{x}}}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

let $f(x)=\frac{1}{1-e^{\frac{1}{x}}}$

Taking the derivative we end up with $$f'(x)=\frac{x^2}{e^{\frac{1}{x}}}$$

Now the textbook says that derivative $f'(x)$ exists. how come? Since $e^{\frac{1}{x}}$ is undefined at $x=0$ how do we conclude that?

Btw we are asked to discuss the existence of $x=0$ Function has discontinuity at $x=0$ but it's derivative at $x=0$ exists

Comment: When you say that the derivative of a function exists, then this means that it exists for all elements in the domain of the function. In your case, $0$ is not in the domain of $f$, so there is no problem with $0$ here.

Comment: There is a typo in your derivative above, I find that with $f(x)= \frac1{ 1-e^{\frac{1}{x}}}$ we get $f'(x)=-\frac{e^{\frac{1}{x}}}{ x^2\left(1-e^{\frac{1}{x}}\right)^2}$, isn't it?

Comment: It certainly is ...

Comment: @OlivierOloa still it doesn't exist at $x=0$

Comment: @math31 Yes, but I think it is better to consider the right expression...

Comment: The limit from both sides gives you the same value. Specifically zero.

Comment: @IanMiller But this way it looks like derivative doesn't exist at $x=0$

Comment: Hmm so the conclusion is that the OP needs to take more care differentiating.