# $f(x)=\frac{1}{1-e^{\frac{1}{x}}}$'s derivative

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I'm asked to compute the derivative of $$f(x)=\frac{1}{1-e^{\frac{1}{x}}}$$
which is defined for all $x \ne 0$. We are asked to discuss the existence of $f'(0)$.

We need to make sure function is continuous to say that the derivative exists. $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{1-e^{\frac{1}{x}}}$$ does not exist, since if I approach $0$ from left I get $1$ but If I approach from right, I get $0$.

Then function is discontinuous thus the derivative at $x=0$ does not exist.

Am I wrong? It seems to me that there is something that I'm forgetting to include.

Also, another question would be: How can we expect a function which is not defined at  a point to have a derivative on that point?

Comment: You may wish to see [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2041943/existence-of-the-derivative-of-the-function-fx-frac11-e-frac1x?rq=1)

Comment: Consider [this function](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/m8jhfbsi77).  Depending on definition, we might say this function has a derivative at $x=0$.

Comment: @SimpleArt depending on definition.
Does my example have a derivative at $x=0$

Comment: Well, would you agree the derivative exists if $\lim_{x\to0}f'(x)$ exists?  Then proceed to take the derivative and see if this is the case.

Comment: @Xenidia I think you are right: as the function cannot be made continuous at zero it can't then be differentiable there under **any** possible definition of $\;f(0)\;$  Case closed. Now, clearly a function undefined at some point cannot be differentiable, or any other thing, *on that point*. Nevertheless it is usually assumed that if the limit of the function at that point exists *finitely* and thus the function can be defined there as its limit, then one can think of trying to evaluate the derivative there.

Answer (score 1):

## First possibility

The function is not defined at $0$, so it cannot have a derivative at $0$.

## Second possibility

We agree that, if the function has a limit at $0$, we consider it to be defined at $0$, with the limit as value. Alas,
$$
\lim_{x\to0^-}f(x)=1,\qquad \lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)=0
$$
So no derivative possible.

## Third possibility

We consider separately

1. $f_+(x)=f(x)$, for $x>0$, and $f_+(0)=0$
2. $f_-(x)=f(x)$, for $x<0$, and $f_-(0)=1$

We have, for $x\ne0$,
$$
f'(x)=-\frac{f(x)^2}{x^2}e^{1/x}
$$
Then,
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}f_+'(x)=\lim_{t\to\infty}-\frac{t^2e^t}{(1-e^t)^2}=0
$$
and also
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}f_-'(x)=0
$$
Thus both $f_+$ and $f_-$ are differentiable at $0$.

## A picture

[image]